# Bind UniformGrid Columns based on parent Width

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to bind a UniformGrid Columns property in a ItemsControl.

So far I have:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scroll" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid>
                    <UniformGrid.Columns>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Columns}">
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                            <Binding Source="{x:Reference scroll}" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </UniformGrid.Columns>
                </UniformGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And in the converter:

```
const double TileWidth = 154;
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    double width, aWidth;
    UniformGrid grid = values[0] as UniformGrid;
    ScrollViewer scroll = values[1] as ScrollViewer;
    var gw = grid.Width;
    var gaw = grid.ActualWidth;

    aWidth = scroll.ActualWidth;
    width = aWidth - (scroll.Padding.Left + scroll.Padding.Right);

    return 3;

    // return width / TileWidth;
}
```

I can't get any of the width's of the parent controls to determine how many columns I want to display.  They are either `0.0` or `NaN`.

How can I get a parent's width to determine how much space is available?

Comment: Maybe a WrapPanel will solve this problem?

Comment: @Tony I was using a WrapPanel but I wanted my items to be evenly spaced, so trying out the UniformGrid

Comment: @Tony that doesn't work, the items get all Left aligned in the WrapPanel not stretched out across the available space.  I tried fiddling with margin's via other converts to determine spacing there as well.

Comment: Have you tried StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost=True

Comment: Using the UniformGrid, Try to create a variable cols and bind it <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding cols}">  Then on Code, calculate how many cols you need, checking ItemsControl1.ActualWidth and set that variable.

Comment: @Tony I'm doing that with the converter.  And the ActualWidth is zero.

Comment: It is inside a Template. This maybe something related to Container. Try using ContainerFromItem to find out the Container and its dimensions Width and Height

Comment: @Tony your suggestion of using a variable cols; I using that idea, as a dependency property and using the ScrollViewer's SizeChanged event made it happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the UniformGrid, Try to create a variable cols and bind it

```
 <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=TileColumns}">
```

Then in code behind, calculate how many columns needed, checking ActualWidth and set that variable.

```
public int TileColumns
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(TileColumnsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TileColumnsProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TileColumns.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty TileColumnsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TileColumns", typeof(int), typeof(TileView), new PropertyMetadata(3));

private void scroll_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var aw = scroll.ActualWidth;
    TileColumns = (int)aw / 154; // 154 is a Tile's width
}
```

Comment: thanks.  Modified your answer so that a future viewer can see what I did to solve the problem based on your suggestion.

Comment: Great! Maybe I will find myself in future googling for a problem like this and then find this anwser here. Hey! This already happened with me. :)